# Python script not outputting in Java

Tags: java, python, python-3.4, processbuilder

Can someone explain why I get no output? The java code outputs errors in the python script just fine, but not the DataFrame that returns when the Python code is successful. Im deploying on a Python 3.4 environment with a python script that looks like this called through Java:

```
d = {'one' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.], index=['a', 'b', 'c']), 
     'two' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])} 
df = pd.DataFrame(d) 

df
```

My Java code calling the python:

```
private static String executePythonCorrelations() {
    String dir=System.getProperty("user.home")+"/insights/";  
    List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();
    commands.add("python3");
    commands.add(dir+"sentiment_corr_conn.py");
    //commands.add(""+_categoryId);
    String ret="";
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder().command(commands);
        final Process p = pb.start();
        BufferedReader output = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader error = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

        String line="";
        while ((line = output.readLine()) != null) {
            ret+=line+"<br/>";
        }

        while ((line = error.readLine()) != null) {
            ret+="ERROR: "+line+"<br/>";
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        return("EXCEPTION: "+e.getMessage()+"<br/>");
    }
    return(ret);
}
```

Comment: Know nothing about python's dataframes, but it doesn't look as if your python script is outputting anything to `stdout` at all?

Comment: Are you sure about `new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())`? Don't you want `p.getOutputStream()` here?

Comment: @dunni Somewhat confusingly, this [getInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream--) seems to be the right stream. It is named like this because `getInputStream` returns an `InputStream`. It's NOT because it is *connected to* `stdin` of the child process, as one might think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you need `print(df)` at the end.  Python's interactive mode displays the value of an expression, but script mode, which is what you're using when you call it from Java, does not.  In your given code, that last line of Python evaluates `df`, but then you don't give it a command (verb) telling the Python run-time system what to do with the value, so it dies sitting on top of the data stack.